# Spring boot test with multiple configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, dependency-injection, integration-testing

In my Spring boot 2.1 project I have different `@Configuration`s for different test (ConfigurationA and ConfigurationB), that reside in different packages. Both configurations define the same set of beans but in a different manner (mocked vs. the real thing)

As I am aware of the [Bean overriding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes) mechanism introduced in Spring Boot 2.1, I have set the property: `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`.

However I do have a test with the following the setup of the following configuration and test class. First there is a `@Configuration` in the productive part (I'm using Maven):

```
package com.stackoverflow;

@Configuration
public class ProdConfiguration{
...
}
```

Then in the test branch there is a general Test `@Configuration` on the same package level:

```
package com.stackoverflow

@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public GameMap gameMap() {
    return Mockito.mock(GameMap.class);
  }
}
```

And in a subpackage I have another `@Configuration`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.impl;

@Configuration
public class RealMapTestConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public GameMap gameMap() {
    return new GameMap("testMap.json");
  }
}
```

And then of course there is the test that is troubling me:

```
package com.stackoverflow.impl;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RealMapTestConfiguration.class, ProdConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("bug") // spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
public class MapImageServiceIT {
  @Autowired
  private GameMap map;
}
```

It turns out that the injected `GameMap` into my test is a mock instance from `TestConfiguration` instead of the real thing from `RealMapTestConfiguration`. Aparrently in my test I have the configuration from `ProdConfiguration` and `TestConfiguration`, when I wanted `ProdConfiguration` and `RealMapTestConfiguration`. As the beans defined in the `ProdConfiguration` and `*TestConfiguration` are different the combination works, but `TestConfiguration` and `RealMapTestConfiguration` define the same been. It seems like the `TestConfiguration` is picked up by component scanning as it is in the same package as `ProdConfiguration`.
I was under the impression that when overriding beans the bean definition that is closer to the test class would be preferred. However this seems not to be the case.

So here are my questions:

1. When overriding beans, what is the order? Which bean overrides which one?
2. How to go about to get the correct instance in my test (using a different bean name is not an option, as in reality the injected bean is not directly used in the test but in a service the test uses and there is no qualifier on it.)

Comment: Did you try using a dedicated integration-testing-profile? Also, since what you return from the configuration is a mock anyway, why don't you use `@MockBean` in your test class?

Comment: @DoeJohnson: Injecting the bean as `MockBean` solved the issues, as I could then define the mocked behaviour in the setup and only use one `TestConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` property, but specifying specific config in a test class has worked fine for me as a way of switching between objects in different tests.

You say...

> It turns out that the injected GameMap into my test is a mock instance from TestConfiguration instead of the real thing from RealMapTestConfiguration.

But RealMapTestConfiguration does return a mock

```
package com.stackoverflow.impl;

@Configuration
public class RealMapTestConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public GameMap gameMap() {
    return Mockito.mock(GameMap.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: The code examples were the wrong way round: `TestConfiguration` returns a mock instance and `RealMapTestConfiguration` returns a real instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that including `ContextConfiguration` nullifies (part of) the effect of `@SpringBootTest`. `@SpringBootTest` has the effect of looking for `@SpringBootConfiguration` in your application (starting from the same package, I believe). However, if `ContextConfiguration` is applied, then configurations are loaded from there.

Another way of saying that: because you have `ContextConfiguration` in your test, scanning for `@Configuration` classes is disabled, and `TestConfiguration` is not loaded.

I don't think I have a full picture of your configuration setup so can't really recommend a best practice here, but a quick way to fix this is to add `TestConfiguration` to your `ContextConfiguration` in your test. Make sure you add it last, so that it overrides the bean definitions in the other two configurations.

The other thing that *might* work is removing `@ContextConfiguration` entirely and letting the `SpringBootApplication` scanning do its thing - that's where what you said about the bean definition that is closest may apply.

Comment: Clarified question. Placing the two configuration files on `@SpringBootTest` and remove `@ContextConfiguration` makes no difference, as `TestConfiguration` is picked up by package scanning and that configuration should not be included.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I believe specifying the classes using `@SpringBootTest` has the same effect as using `ContextConfiguration` - you can set `debug=true` in your application.properties to see which configuration Spring is using.
Either way, sounds like @MockBean does what you want to, too.

Answer (score 1):

In that case just don't use @Configuration on configuration class and import it to the test manually using @Import, example:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(MyTest.MyTestConfig.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private String string;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    static class MyTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public String string() {
            return "String";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.. thanks a lot. I had `@TestConfiguration` on my test mock classes and that was interfering with the main application.

Comment: We can mark the @TestConfiguration as primary, so that test cases will consider this as primary bean and won't complain.