# @TestConfiguration mock objects incorrectly picked up and used in actual (non-test) Spring Boot application run

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have several `@TestConfiguration` classes to be used for **unit tests only** with `SpringBootTest` as follows

```
@TestConfiguration
public class MockApplicationServiceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ApplicationService applicationService() {  
       return new ApplicationService() {
         //...
       }
    }
```

and then in the unit test I do

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(value = "MockApplicationServiceConfiguration.class")
```

These unit tests work and correctly substitute the mock configuration objects in place of actual-run objects.
But then when I run the **actual** application, by starting MainApplication.java which has the real autowired dependencies, I see that the mock objects are being used, even for the actual application run!

The project is divided into `main & test` as below. Why is the actual run picking up the Test Configuration objects?

[image]

Comment: Something's messed up the classpath used to run your main application and is incorrectly including test code. That could be your IDE, build system, accidentally having the code in `main`, and so on. Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090558/1005607): **remove `@TestConfiguration`** from the mocked Import'ed classes. Now the real application doesn't load these objects, while the `@SpringBootTest` tests still load it via `@Import`!

Even though `@TestConfiguration` is supposed to be test-only, Spring still treats it as a `@Configuration`, apparently, which impacts the real app run.

The following works: no `@TestConfiguration` on the mock object, and `@SpringBootTest/Import` as before:

```
public class MockApplicationServiceConfiguration {
  //..
}

@SpringBootTest
@Import(value = "MockApplicationServiceConfiguration.class")
```